# Prolog - Why can't you call/1 a clause made with (=..)/2?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

The following piece of code:

```
Clause =.. [integer,1],
```

results in Clause = integer(1)

I would expect that using call/1 on the Clause variable results in true. However, SWI prolog tells me that the "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated".

```
Clause =.. [integer,1],
call(Clause).
```

Why doesn't this work? I have seen this technique being used in the book by Bratko.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to check this, and post exactly what happens, as this works fine for me in SWI Prolog.

Comment: Could you try it in the online SWI prolog? https://swish.swi-prolog.org/

Comment: Maybe this is the explanation: "SWISH is a limited subset of SWI-Prolog"

Comment: Clearly a limitation of SWISH Prolog. In SWISH, `Clause =.. [integer,1].` and `call(integer(1)).` yield expected results.